# Error with importing android project *Android Studio*

Tags: git, android-studio

I am implementing a git project into my android project.  When i added the git's project java classes they turned red.

I found this question. But the answers don't work for me.
*[Android Studio - All file names in project are red but there are no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246043/android-studio-all-file-names-in-project-are-red-but-there-are-no-errors)*

I thought the answer would be, because of VCS control, and i need to delete the .idea folder. But i have looked everywhere in my project and their is no .idea folder.

Comment: Did you add the dependencies in gradle?

Comment: which gradle do i go to?  build.gradle?  And what depedencies?  My gradle folder has turned red too.

Comment: what should i put in the dependencies?  'compile'?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are adding new files to a Git project. In this case, AndroidStudio will turn those files red because they haven't been staged or committed yet.

Try navigating to your project and typing `git status`. You should see those same files as unstaged.

To resolve this, simply stage those files to git (you can use `git add -a` to add them all at once) and they should turn green. Alternately, you can right click on those red files -> Git -> Add.

Finally, after you've committed the files, they should turn blue.

Comment: i am not trying to push to a git repo. I downloaded some files off a git repo.  When i added those files into my projects folder, the files turned red in android studio.

Comment: `git add` doesn't push anything to the git repo. Only `git push` will push to the repo. Because you downloaded your project from a git repo, any new files that weren't part of the git repo will be in red. By adding or committing those new files, they will turn green or blue.