# Red files in Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a android studio project and some of the files have turned red.

I have tried the anwsers from this question '[Error with importing android project *Android Studio*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816810/error-with-importing-android-project-android-studio/33816992#33816992)'

but none works.

So i thought about about adding some dependencies.

So i added this `compile fileTree9dir: 'activity', include ['*java'])`

Then the files will turn blue, like they should. But only for 5 seconds and then they turn back to red.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are seeing the File Status colors that Android Studio uses to show the status of the file. Open Settings and go to Editor > Colors & Fonts > File Status. Here you can see what all of the different colors mean. My guess is that your reddish files are that color because you have not yet added them to source control.

Comment: **Update:** now in **Android Studio** see

**`Settings` > `Version Control` > `File status colors`**